# Make only link-text clickable on hover

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to make a h1 link that transforms when hovering over it. This works perfectly, when placing the /a outside of h1 However, doing this resolves in making the whole element react and clickable when hovering over it - it just looks bad. Placing /a inside /h1 makes only the text clickable as desired - yet it doesn't react to hover, but to all other changes it does.

Please note that I am a beginner and I do not know what exact context is required for you to help me.

This lets hover work, but makes the whole element clickable.

```css
#headlines a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_6" style="color: black; text-align: center">
    <a href="headlines.html"
       id="headlines"
       style="text-decoration: none; color: black">
        <h1> Headlines 
          </h1></a>
        <hr>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply transform to the `h1` on hover...but make the `h1` as `display:inline-block` so it's no bigger than it needs to be.

The link will **always** be clickable but it should solve the sizing issue.

```css
a#headlines h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

a#headlines h1 {
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

a#headlines h1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_6" style="color: black; text-align: center">
  <a href="headlines.html" id="headlines" style="text-decoration: none; color: black">
    <h1> Headlines
    </h1>
  </a>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. But why do All elements surrounding the transforming element do back away from it and return back to their position after transforming back. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `inline-block`....a transform is purely visual, it shouldn't affect layout.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah, I copied your code. It changed my layout a bit from the beginning on and is changing it even more when transforming. Though it works as intended - only the text is clickable. I am using a 12 column grid - does this affect the transform in any way?

Answer (score 1):

you can try it

```
a#headlines:hover {
 transition: transform .5s ease;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
 a {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 45px;
    transition: all 500ms;
}

 a:hover {
    font-size:60px;
    font-size-adjust: 20px;
}
```

This is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5ceuxzm/5/)

Comment: Why does this only work with font-size but not with transform: scale? :o

Comment: The answers that you received from Girraj and Paulie_D are both working fine. I'm not sure what do you mean